# how can we create hexagon shape in network vis.js

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-network

I am using the Network layout and I wanted to show node in a hexagon shape, for that, I have added following in code snippet in the lib/network/shapes.js

```
/**
  Draw a Hexagon shape with 6 sides
  @Param {Number} x horizontal center
  @Param {Number} y vertical center
  @Param {Number} r radius
 */
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.hexagon = function(x, y, r) {
  var a = Math.PI2 / 6;

  this.beginPath();
  this.translate(x, y);
  this.moveTo(radius, 0);

  for (var i = 1; i < sides; i++) {
    this.lineTo(radiusMath.cos(ai), radiusMath.sin(ai));
  }
  this.closePath();
};
```

should I need to update the vis.js file too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer https://github.com/almende/vis/pull/3420, and it also merged in the vis.js github